# How to properly inflate fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

[This code](https://www.journaldev.com/10380/android-google-maps-example-tutorial) displays a Google map and some markers on it. It works just fine on my Galaxy Note 4. Strangely, it crashes when integrated with my app.

**MapActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        //  mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trisakti_map);
        //  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-6.166434, 106.79781))
                .title("Universitas Trisakti"));

    }
}
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="app.devbyzero.net.pascasarjanatrisakti.MapActivity"
   >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/trisakti_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat said:

> 12-29 11:00:26.893 3623-3623/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: app.devbyzero.net.pascasarjanatrisakti, PID: 3623
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{app.devbyzero.net.pascasarjanatrisakti/app.devbyzero.net.pascasarjanatrisakti.MapActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML
>   file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)

Of course, when the fragment part in the xml is commented, there's no crash. Weird, because I took this fragment code from a working example :/

So, how do I fix this inflating issue?

Comment: use  `<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: Try replacing fragment with FrameLayout in your xml.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

Comment: @SonuSanjeev the same "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

check if the package name is correct, remove the below lines

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="app.devbyzero.net.pascasarjanatrisakti.MapActivity"
```

also make sure u added these in your manifest :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_places_api_key" />
```